# how to call a method every time in jquery after page reload?

Tags: jquery

Is there any method in jQuery which gets called each and every time the page gets reloaded? If there is, how can I make use of that method in my JS file?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code here... */ })`

Comment: MY requirement is different. I have a method and It should get called from $(document).ready(function(){    }).

Comment: So what's stopping you from calling the method in the document.ready?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() { ... })
```

*whenever the user refreshes the page this function invokes, the code you want to execute can be placed inside the function*

Comment: waiting for details....! I don't get it what is been answered here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use: `$(function(){ /* your code here */ });`